# Python : GridSearchCV is taking too long to execute

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, gridsearchcv

I am running GridSearchCV on small dataset, which size is (13380,37) and code is as below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV,GridSearchCV
parameters = {kernel:('linear','rbf','poly'),'C':[1.5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'gamma':[1e-7,1e-6,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2]}
svc = SVC() 
clf = GridSearchCV(svc,parameters,n_jobs=38)
search = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
search.best_params_
```

It is running for more than a day. But with the same parameters if i run it on iris dataset,it is giving the result in 1 min. The data is standardized and using multiprocessing too. Am i missing anything here.

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to n_jobs, please refer to this [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34416/scikit-learn-n-jobs-parameter-on-cpu-usage-memory)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the njobs you indicated. change it from 38 to -1 and that should do the job fast enough.